# Load products without category association

Tags: magento2, orm

I've been looking for a way to load products without a category in Magento2. I'm working on a cleanup script that will automatically assign them to a relevant category, but at a loss implementing the initial query.

Practically every post I've found has suggested to load a category by id, then call a method on the category to get the related products, however my scenario is different.

Here's my first sad attempt, which performs a direct query to find the products without a category association, then a typical ProductRepository method to load the products by sku.

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class ProductHelper
{
    private
        $_oProductRepo,
        $_oSearchCriteriaBuilder,
        $_oResource;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $oProductRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $oSearchCriteriaBuilder,
        ResourceConnection $oResource
    ) {
        $this->_oProductRepo           = $oProductRepository;
        $this->_oSearchCriteriaBuilder = $oSearchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_oResource              = $oResource;
    }

    public function loadProductsWithoutCat()
    {
        // Raw query to find product skus with no associated category
        $oDbConn = $this->_oResource->getConnection(
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);

        $mResult = $oDbConn->rawQuery(
            'SELECT `e`.sku ' .
            'FROM   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ' .
            'WHERE  e.entity_id NOT IN '.
            '(SELECT `cat`.`product_id` FROM `catalog_category_product` AS `cat`)');

        // Extract skus from result
        $aProducts = $mResult->fetchAll();
        $aSkus     = [];
        foreach($aProducts as $aProduct) {
            $aSkus[] = $aProduct['sku'];
        }

        // Load the product objects
        $oSearchCriteria = $this
            ->_oSearchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('sku', $aSkus, 'in')
            ->create();

        return $this->_oProductRepo->getList($oSearchCriteria)->getItems();
    }
}
```

While this approach works, is there a *proper* way for this type of search in Magento2?